# IKEA Loviken Faucet disassembly assistance requested

Tags: plumbing-fixture, kitchen-sink

My kitchen faucet drips a bit from the hot water tap. I've found the [manual](http://www.ikea.com/ms/en_US/customer_service/assembly/L/L00050764.pdf), which is somewhat helpful, but I'm unable to remove the part 118211 shown on page 3.

[image: Diagram of IKEA Loviken faucet]

There is a exterior top screw cap, which exposes a very small interior phillips head screw. When the interior phillips is loosened, I'm unable to get the handle to come off. I'm also unsure if part 118211 is easily replaced here in the US, although I've found a number of posts concerning it in the UK. Any tips or info is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

> **When the interior phillips is loosened,**

You should remove it, not just loosen it.

Then the handle should lift off vertically.

This should allow you to remove the cover/washer part

Then you should be able to see the hexagonal top of the valve assembly
and remove it with the corresponding sized <strike>spanner</strike> wrench (or adjustable nut-rounder)

> **My kitchen faucet drips a bit**

I'd investigate if the valve unit can be tightened and whether everything is seating correctly / whether there is trapped debris or damage. There might be a rubber/plastic washer you can replace.

> **I'm also unsure if part 118211 is easily replaced here in the US**

It is easily *replaced* in the US, it might not be easily *obtained* in the US :-)

I'd

- Ask IKEA about obtaining replacement part 118211.
- Take part 118211 to the local hardware store / DIY-shed and show it to the oldest person there.
- Send money to Sweden.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer, and direction! I'll report back when I've tried some/all of the recommendations